# No veo los nombres de mis Tabs en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

*Buenas, tengo un problemita nada grave pero por algún motivo no se ven los títulos de mis tabs. En mi diseño, se pueden ver los nombres:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el código:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/negro"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
            android:text="Book Search"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/negro">
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabLibro"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="uno"/>
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabAnime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="dos"/>
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabVideo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="tres"/>
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Y este es el código de mi `MainActivity`:

```
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs));
        tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public PlaceholderFragment() { }
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                                 ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    LibrosFragment lf = new LibrosFragment();
                    return lf;
                case 1:
                    AnimeFragment af = new AnimeFragment();
                    return af;
                case 2:
                    YoutubeFragment yf = new YoutubeFragment();
                    return yf;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }
```

Así se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma en que pude solucionarlo fue borrando los `TabItems` de la `Activity` quedando el `TabLayout` sin nada dentro:

```
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Y luego desde la `clase` los añadí por código:

```
    TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Libros"));
    tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Series"));
    tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Música"));
```

Y comenté la siguiente línea porque generaba conflictos cerrando la app:

```
    //tabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Answer (score 1):

No soy un gran programador en android pero no te faltaria este código:

```
  <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

Despues de cerrar:

```
  </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Pues, la verdad es que sí lo tengo solo que no lo he añadido en el código de la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

El color del texto y el indicador seguramente es negro.

Define un estilo en `styles.xml` el cual defina el color de background y el indicador del tab:

```
<style name="AppTheme.TabLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout">
    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

ahora este estilo definelo en tu `TabLayout` :

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
     android:id="@+id/tabs"
     style="@style/AppTheme.TabLayout"
     ...
     ...
     >

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Comment: Pues no, sigue igual